# Using web api in a web forms environment

Tags: webforms, asp.net-web-api

Why does the WebApi controller have to end in the word Controller to work in a web forms environment?[Microsoft demo referenced this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/23/using-asp-net-web-api-with-asp-net-web-forms.aspx)

> Note: Make sure the name ends in “Controller” and not “Controller1” or
>   similar.

Comment: Lets assume that I dont want it called XXXController, how do i add a correct route iny in Application_start method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is part of Microsoft's strategy (many software companies are following this paradigm) of [Convention Over Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) for their newer technologies.

Wikipedia entry:

> Convention over configuration (also known as coding by convention) is
>   a software design paradigm which seeks to decrease the number of
>   decisions that developers need to make, gaining simplicity, but not
>   necessarily losing flexibility. The phrase essentially means a
>   developer only needs to specify unconventional aspects of the
>   application. For example, if there's a class Sale in the model, the
>   corresponding table in the database is called “sales” by default. It
>   is only if one deviates from this convention, such as calling the
>   table “products_sold”, that one needs to write code regarding these
>   names. When the convention implemented by the tool matches the desired
>   behavior, it behaves as expected without having to write configuration
>   files. Only when the desired behavior deviates from the implemented
>   convention is explicit configuration required.

Comment: Lets assume that I dont want it called XXXController, how do i add a correct route iny in my Application_start method

Comment: @gh9: I don't know, I haven't tried. I would recommend sticking to convention on this however. Trying to force out of COC might give you serious headaches.

Comment: You can change the convention by replacing the default implementation of IHttpControllerSelector, but that's orthogonal to whether you are using Web Forms. See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection